# MySQL SELECT statement using PHP GET variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have a PHP script that is generating a MySQL select statement:

select * from words where word = 'Classic'

There is exactly one word in the words table with the variable word equal to Classic.

When my PHP page executes, I get no results from the query. If I echo the string that is being used to execute the query, cut and paste that into the SQL window in PHPMyAdmin in the database, I also get no results. However, if I re-type that EXACT string into the SQL window in PHPMyAdmin (with the same quote characters), I get the proper result of one row.

The word Classic from the select statement is gotten from a PHP GET (see code below). I can echo the $word variable, and get the correct result of 'Classic'. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

  require ('dbconnect.php');

  $word = $_GET["word"];

  $selectStr = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = '" . $word . "'";

  if ($results = MySQL($dbName, $selectStr))
  {
    $rowCount = MySQL_NUMROWS($results);
  }

  $resultRow = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($results);

  $wordID = $resultRow[0];

?>
```

Comment: you should NEVER use a request variable directly on a SQL statement.

Comment: It does not answer your question, but remember you **must** always sanitize user input before using it in a query to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: can there be any case sensitivity issue???

Comment: OK, so should I use a post instead?

Comment: Use PDO to execute your queries........

Comment: What error are you getting back from the DB? I assume the DB class/functions you are using allow you to access this.

Comment: What database library are you using here? If it supports [placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you should be using those before you get yourself into serious trouble.

Comment: My application is controlling what variables will be GET and POSTed. So there is no user variability.

Comment: Matt, you might want to read "Essential PHP security" or something first. Quick and easy read that covers the basics. There's nothing stopping me from sending arbitrary data to your endpoint.

Comment: @Matt: there is no such thing as controlling get/post. That's user-provided data from the get go. It is **BEYOND* trivial to manipulate GET data by just editing the url the browser is hitting, and POST can be forged with a simple client-side .html file that posts directly to your script. You are BEGGING to get your server hacked.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, please, please sanitize that word. `mysql_real_escape_string()` should do the trick.

`$selectStr = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '" . $sanitized_word_i_promise . "'";` should work :)

Just to explain: "=" should work for exact matches. This includes uppercase / lowercase, spaces etc. You should probably trim that result first too, before using it in the query.

If you have `foo` stored in the database (note the space at the end) - it won't match `foo`, without a space. You'll want to use `LIKE 'foo%'` - probably.

Either way, Sourabh is right, although performance wise, this isn't a big hit when trying to match exact strings, you should look for the problem in other places first (such as, is the item in the database an exact match?).

Comment: using like is not a good option when he wants an exact match. performance will be bad

Comment: OK. Understood. With the word sanitized, and using the LIKE statement, I got it to work properly. Thank you!

Comment: You might try trim on the word too and removing the LIKE statement. Could be simple whitespace that make the = operator not work and the LIKE work.  Can use php trim() or mysql, depending on which server is less utilized.

Answer (score 2):

First off you should not take any user input and directly input it into a query without sanitizing it, or using a prepared statement.

Now that we've gotten that out of the way: have you tried doing a strcmp() with the variable and your string written in? Such as

> echo strcmp($_GET['word'], "Classic")

If you get a result other than 0 it means they are not the same, most likely there will be a whitespace of some sort in the $_GET variable. use `trim()` on it to take out whitespace. Also could be a case sensitivity issue as well.

Comment: I get a 1, which means the words are not the same. But I have tried using trim() and mysql_real_escape_string(), and the strings still do not match.

Comment: Probably some upper/lower case issue.